# Can I install a Windows 7 Virtual Machine using the Disc?

Tags: windows-7, mac, virtual-machine

I need to setup a Windows 7 Virtual Machine on a MAC.

I'm wondering, if I have a windows 7 installer Disc, can I use that to install the image? or does it have to be a specific ISO in order to install on a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Any VM system can install an operating system from a physical disk.

Alternately, you can create an ISO image of the disk and install the VM OS from that ISO image.